# Integration of fckeditor in Social engine tepmplate

Tags: php, smarty

I want to integrate FCK editor instead of text area filed in social engine .tpl file.
Does Any one know ?
How to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs.  They show how to integrate by hardcoding & initializing via PHP, or via JS.  Make sure you use the latest version (which is called CKEditor).

Comment: Thanks for your answer
What type of documents i have to check for this

Comment: Go to the CKEditor website & take a look.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you give TinyMCE a try?  It's, at least in my experience, a lot lighter weight and faster.